# Azure API Management - how to handle paged response from backend API

Tags: pagination, azure-api-management

I have created an API in Azure API Management to get data from a backend API.

The result from the backend API is paged, including a 'next' url in the response which must be used for the next request.

How to handle this 'next' url, in order to concatenate all paged responses and return the total of all paginated responses as one single response through Azure APIM?

Answer (score 0):

That would be quite complex policy, but could be done by combining retry and send-request. In short keep retrying request every time with next url and concatenating results as long as there is next link in response.

Comment: Did you ever try this to see if it would work?  We have the same challenge now?

Comment: Yes, it would work, with a few caveats: 1. This will increase request latency, so client terminating request before you get all items is likely. 2. As you accumulate items gateway may ran out of memory 3. As number of items grow #1 and #2 will become worse and worse and will cause issues at some point. It's really more beneficial to work with client to accept paged results.